# Should I check if an item is already in a set before adding it?

Tags: python, set

If `foo` is a builtin `set` that I know contains `"bar"`, which of these is faster? Which is more Pythonic?

```
foo.add("bar")
```

or

```
if "bar" not in foo:
    foo.add("bar")
```

Comment: No just add it. It is likely more expensive to check first and then add it (though you could time it to confirm).

Comment: What's the meaning of using set if you still need to check the membership before adding?

Comment: if `x in y` is faster than `y.add(x)`, then the answer is "it depends". You might prefer your first code sample if you expect collisions to be very rare, and your second code sample if collisions are very common. (I don't actually know whether `x in y` is faster than `y.add(x)`, that's just idle speculation)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Actually, the second  **may** be faster (output from IPython):

```
In [2]: %timeit s.add("a")
The slowest run took 68.27 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
10000000 loops, best of 3: 73.3 ns per loop

In [3]: %timeit if not "a" in s: s.add("a")
10000000 loops, best of 3: 37.1 ns per loop
```

But anyway, **the first one is more Pythonic**, I agree.

Comment: That's because looking up `s.add`, then calling it, has a higher cost than the membership test (which is handled with one bytecode test). But if the element is *missing* most of the time, testing first is slower.

Comment: they are both `O(1)` operations ... membership may be marginally faster based on overhead stuff ... but they are essentially identical

Comment: In other words: don't rely on this oversimplified test in real situations unless you *know for a fact* that you have a situation where the majority of elements being added are *already there*.

Answer (score 2):

The pythonic way is to do first, ask later. Just add it to the set.

Asking first is more common in languages such as C.

Performance is usually not key in python code. Readability is usually much more important, so writing ideomatic code is good practice.